# Limiting Watson Assistant user response to ONLY Numbers - No text allowed

Tags: artificial-intelligence, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

Hi I'm training my Watson Assistant (Classic) to ask the question, "How much is your vehicle worth?" If assistant recognizes @sys_number, their response saved in a variable $vehicleworth as " `< ? input.text ? >` ". This was fine until a user accidentally wrote 5--- instead of 5000. This was saved as just 5 instead of 5000.

The question is: How or can I limit the user's input to only numbers? Or what would I be able to do to recognize this "5---" as an incorrect input?

Thanks in advance!
Respectfully.

Answer (score 2):

In Watson Assistant Actions:
you can use [regex validation](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson-assistant?topic=watson-assistant-collect-info#customer-response-type-regex) , there are good examples [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson-assistant?topic=watson-assistant-collect-info#regex-examples)

In Watson Assistant Classic create entities with a pattern as described [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-entities#entities-patterns)

Comment: Thanks, is this available in the Classic Watson Assistant?

Comment: @HarveyBot I've updated my answer to include Classic

Answer (score 0):

In Watson Assistant, you could perform an input check. You could try to [convert the input to a number](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson-assistant?topic=watson-assistant-expression-methods-actions#expression-methods-actions-numbers). If the conversion fails, the result is **null**. After the conversion, you would check for null and respond that invalid input was entered and ask again.